# C# Как по элементу List'a узнать название массива?

Tags: c#, list

В общем вопрос аналогичен с заголовком темы. **Как собственно имея элемент списка  узнать откуда растут ноги?** За одно может сможете подсказать варианты реализации поиска. У меня есть несколько листингов с данными и текстБокс. В списках к примеру хранятся имена в таком виде (Фамилия;Имя*Возраст$дата). В текстБоксе ввожу "Фамилия" разделяя Split'ом по ";" символу и запоминаю индекс в массиве. Мне нужно сравнить введенную фамилию с той что в массиве. Если данные там имеется, то извлечь остальную информацию о человеке, зная название списка и индекс элемента так же разделять по символам и добавлять. Простите что по всему видимому изобретаю велосипед.

Comment: Да, видимо, велосипед... Давайте с самого начала - если верно понимаю, есть некие наборы данных, есть пользовательский ввод. Необходимо проверить, есть ли то, что ввел пользователь в наборе данных, и, если введенное есть, то вывести дополнительные данные из набора. Так?

Comment: Да, все верно. После разделения по символу теряю доп. данные.

Comment: Тогда бы я переиначил подход к работе с данными в целом, если это возможно. Как именно - масса способов, от таблиц в базе данных до создания специального класса для этого. Попробую дать ответ именно по способу с созданием класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для хранения ваших данных давайте создадим самый простой класс, полями которого бы являлись Фамилия, имя, отчество, возраст, дата и т.д... Пусть этот класс назовем `Person`. После этого уже создаем новый списочек, элементами которого будут экземпляры этого класса, и вот с ними уже будем работать.

```
//Класс для хранения данных
public class Person
{
    public string _family; //Фамилия
    public string _name; //Имя
    public string _surname; //Отчество
    public int _age; //Возраст
    public DateTime _birthdate; //Дата рождения

    //Конструктор класса (может быть не обязательно таким)
    public Person(string family, string name, string surname, string age, DateTime birthdate)
    {
        this._family = family;
        this._name = name;
        this._surname = surname;
        this._age = 40;
        this._birthdate = birthdate;
    }
}

...

//Теперь объявим коллекцию для хранения данных.
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

//Добавляем новую запись
Person human = new Person("Иванов", "Иван", "Иванович", 40, DateTime.Parse("11.10.1976"));
people.Add(human);
...
```

А дальше уже можете работать с `people` как через LINQ, так и напрямую, например, так:

```
foreach(var p in people)
{
    if (p.Name == "Иван")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Полные данные: " + p._family + " " + p._name + " " + p._surname + " Возраст: " + p._age.ToString() + " Дата рождения: " + p._birthdate.ToShortDateString());
    }
}
```

Соответственно, код приведен в качестве примера только лишь.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Ответ более чем исчерпывающий! =))) P.S немного поковыряв свой код я все таки добился адекватной работы. Правда на извлечение всех доп. данных потребовалось 6 циклов... Боюсь представить как бы он работал с большими списками xD Спасибо вам! Воспользуюсь лучше вашим вариантом =))

Comment: @Igrize, you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Краткий ответ на вопрос: Никак.

В вашем случае первое, что необходимо делать при получении новой строки (или массива строк )  вида (Фамилия;Имя*Возраст$дата) это инициализировать этой строкой новый экземпляр класса Person ( написанный вами же класс, содержит поля фамилия, имя, возраст, дата, методы поиска и перегруженные методы сравнения ).

В Листе вы храните объекты класса Person. Когда получаете запрос на поиск по фамилии/имени/возрасту/дате - фильтруете лист с помощью LINQ ( List.Where(..) ) запроса и далее уже работаете с результатом как вам нужно.

PS: При разборе строки (Фамилия;Имя*Возраст$дата) рекомендую использовать регулярные выражения. Для упрощения их составления я бы порекомендовал конструктор решарпера.

Answer (score 1):

Пускай у вас есть класс (выше в ответе был приведен) `Person`, и у вас есть список людей `List<Person> People` При вводе в текстбокс (если вы не дружите с MVVM) можете обработать, допустим событие KeyDown и в обработчике прописать

```
MyListBox.SelectedItem = People.Where(p => p.Famaly.ToLower().Contains(MyTextBox.Text.ToLower()));
```